# Насчет дизайна сайта... Творческий кризис или непостоянство?

Tags: html, css, дизайн, веб-дизайн

Сейчас разрабатываю сайт своей веб-студии. Хотя больше разрабатываю не сайт, а дизайн. Я придумал уже около 7 полноценных дизайнов, воплощал их наполовину (сначала изображал на листке, потом кодом). Они офигенные. Простые, в плоском стиле, интересные, с изюминкой. Но когда воплощу идею наполовину, она надоедает и начинает казаться ужасной, тупой, неинтересной и корявой. В итоге перебрал уже кучу вариантов, и не могу прийти к золотой середине. Я планирую заработать при помощи этой веб-студии, но.... Но я даже для себя не могу пока сайт создать! Что делать? Как придумать *то самое*? Где взять изюминку? Как избавиться от творческого кризиса? Безысходность полнейшая! Внутри как все съело... Деньги нужны, хочу реализовать себя, но...

P.S. 17 лет мне)) Строго не судите))

Comment: даже если "ужасно, тупо и коряво", доведите до конца работу. спросите мнение других. кто ищет, тот найдет.

Comment: Порой "больно" читать подобные вопросы..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

поставьте цель. не большую. на определенном этапе планирования, согласуйте все. начните реализовывать, затем перейдите к этапу завершения и конец.

проделывая это, не стоит как то сильно откланяться от от запланированного направления, потом, по завершению, как сдадите все под ключ, вы можете, если будет желание, проанализировать все, и сделать цикл улучшений по схеме с которой вы начинали(инициализация-> планирование -> выполнение -> завершение). Таким образом вы создадите вторую версию. ...главное начать, определиться и начать делать и закончить работу. важно закончить работу!

Answer (score 1):

где мои 17 лет… тоже хотелось всё и сразу

А это вы попали в классический замкнутый круг программистов — всегда есть время переписать, но ни когда нет времени дописать до конца

Не стоит быть на столько субъективным, пока ваши сайты не кто не видел. Доделайте до конца — покажите людям, вот тогда вы узнаете каков результат вашей работы

Answer (score 0):

Дизайн сайта веб студии не такой важный фактор для потока клиентов, знаю по своему опыту. Пока будете писать Джаконду столько времени пройдет, что может быть и студия уже и не понадобится)).Сделайте средний, но рабочий сайт и начни уже работать. Шедевр будете писать параллельно основной работе. Не путайте цель со средством.

P.S.: Был в такой же ситуации. Решил её именно так как и описал. И прекрасно то, что вы в 17 лет делаете бизнес.